# Drone community spin-off?

Tags: discussion, status-deferred

UAV's (unmanned aerial vehicles), a.k.a. "drones", could be considered a hybrid offspring of Aviation and Robotics.

Since many questions pertaining to drones are considered off-topic in the [Aviation community on SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com), some have decided to attempt to create a spin-off community, [DRONES (at this time, still in the proposal phase, needing more popular participation to be created).](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/107036/drones)

Should this community (Robotics) also shun drone-related questions?  Is it desirable to restrict the scope of this community, or to expand it and embrace drones in their full magnitude?

Comment: We should revisit this question once Drones.SE has been in Beta for a while.

Comment: @MarkBooth It will be interesting.  Like looking back at bulletin board chats (oldtimer, here).

Answer (score 4):

We shouldn't be closing questions which are [on-topic](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, just because they are drone questions, but if Drones Stack Exchange takes off, we may find people prefer it even for questions which are on-topic here.

For details of what our current policy on which drone questions are considered on-topic here, have a look at the [info page](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/tags/uav/info) for any of the [uav](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/uav) [auv](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/auv) and [ugv](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ugv) drone tags.

Also, I'm more than happy to consider suggested edits to the drone tags ([uav](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/136), [auv](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/159) & [ugv](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/162)), suggesting (initially) that people might want to support the drones proposal and (later) that the Drones Beta may be a good place to ask drones questions which are considered off-topic in *Robotics* but on-topic there.

Comment: very useful guidance, tks!

Answer (score 3):

I think that the real question is, *are there enough on-topic questions to support a drone site?* The problem I've seen with drone questions in general are that they're generally off-topic.

The bulk of the questions I've seen about drones are people looking for design questions. If it starts, "How do I..." then the question is probably off topic. Person A could provide one valid answer, and Person B could provide a completely different, but still perfectly valid answer.

For example, a question might be, "How do I extend the flight time of my quadcopter?" Person A might answer, "Add batteries." Person B might answer, "Reduce total weight." Both answers are equally valid.

The better **question** would be, "What specifications affect flight time of a quadcopter?" This type of rephrasing is the gist of the [Q&A is hard, let's go shopping](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) post that we frequently cite for closing questions.

Again, the types of quadcopter questions I see most are all generally off-topic, and typically start:

- "How do I..." (autonomy, obstacle avoidance, build a flight controller, etc.)
- "What's the best..." (quadcopter, flight controller, transmitter, etc.)
- "Where can I find..." (software package, drone that meets specification X, etc.)

Comment: this is a valid comment.  I am sure that, as the technology permeates applications beyond toys (i do not consider hobbies = toys), you will see better questons overall.

Comment: @tonygil - Questions such as what? If I recall correctly, I think you need something like ten or twenty sample questions for a site beta. What questions would you imagine would be asked that don't fall into the open-ended, off-topic classes of questions I've described? :Edit: sorry it's [five questions](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) for the *proposal*. The site is open when it goes to beta (like Robotics). I would urge you to read the section of the page I linked regarding "subsumed" sites, too.

Comment: I apologize, but I fail to understand what you mean by your comment.

Comment: @tonygil - What are five exemplary questions that would be on topic for the drone site that do not fall entirely within Robotics or entirely within Engineering?

Comment: Easy @Chuck, any "Questions about remotely controlled UAVs are probably off topic on Robotics", as mentioned in the descriptions of the [tag:auv], [tag:uav] & [tag:ugv] tags.

Comment: @chuck: to many to name, please check the prposal, there are GOOD questions out there.  BTW, i UPVOTED your answer, regardless of fully agreeing with it or not.

Answer (score 1):

There is now the [Drones Stack Exchange](https://drones.stackexchange.com/).